# Retrieving all selected values from multiselect and show it in the title on hover Jquery

Tags: jquery, select, user-interface, widget, multi-select

I implemented the jQuery UI [MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/)

It is working perfectly. Is there any way I can show all the selected options in the title separated by the comma, on hover? I do not want to expand the header and show more than 4 selections.

Comment: Yes there is a way... 1. Read the Documentation, 2. Learn about the provided Methods and choose `getChecked` which returns an array of all the checked checkboxes. Hook into the `click` Event (Events-Section) and add the title attribute programmatically.

Comment: Could you give an example? I am new in Jquery.

Comment: Provide an working example of your Code on JSfiddle an i will extend the functionality of your code to your needs.

Comment: The working example is http://jsfiddle.net/Mona/5KvP3/

Comment: The working example is in http://jsfiddle.net/Mona/5KvP3/. I want to populate the checked values separated by comma in the Title on hover or as tooltip on hover. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/5KvP3/4/

```
$("#state")
    .multiselect()
    .bind("multiselectclick multiselectcheckall multiselectuncheckall", function( event, ui ){
        var checkedValues = $.map($(this).multiselect("getChecked"), function( input ){
            return input.title;
        });
        $('button.ui-multiselect').attr('title',checkedValues.join(', '));
    })
    .triggerHandler("multiselectclick")
    .multiselectfilter();
```

Comment: Is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly that's what I wanted.

Comment: I am using lot of select boxes calling them by ID. After implementing this script, all the selectbox title is showing the same options selected in their title whatever I selected for one ID. Can we use something specific for that ID other than button.ui-multiselect?